# Pronunciation of interjection "ого"

Tags: произношение, междометие

I've always thought it should be pronounced with the standard Russian voiced velar stop **Г** [g]. But lately i've been hearing recordings where it's pronounced as voiced glottal fricative [ɦ] like the Ukrainian **Г**.

This pronunciation also represents the word in both [Russian](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) and [English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) articles of Wiktionary, and in 2 out of 3 audio examples on [Forvo](https://ru.forvo.com/word/%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE/#ru), all of which are by residents of Russia.

Or is there no 'correct' pronunciation, or is it region dependent within Russia?

Comment: I think both variants are "standard" - at least personally (a "native Moscovian") I recall myself using *both* variants putting slightly different meaning in them (with [ɦ] version expressing more suprise). My first guess is that the voiced velar stop version is most likely inspired by "Spb" pronunciation (probably similar to "что/што" thing).

Comment: https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=ocY0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=i9pv3lhhol&sig=ACfU3U2kE3PKdHmfQKHpKMZ3B8hDEiQffQ&w=1280

Comment: @Alex_ander thank you, i'm ready to accept your reply should you post it as an answer

Comment: I personally think that оХо is more used in Moscow and the Oblast, though it is just personal impression

Comment: To be fair, both of those Wiktionary pronunciations are by the guy called 1640max on Forvo. (Generally when you find a male pronunciation of a Russian word on Wiktionary, it's him, and this is no exception.) So you're actually only finding two pronunciations like that, and one counterexample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Русский язык. Учебник для ссузов, Москва, 2010, с. 38:

> **Орфоэпия согласных**
>
> ... Лишь в нескольких словах **нужно** произносить
> заднеязычные щелевые (похожие на [х] и [х'], но только звонкие) звуки,
> которые принято транскрибировать как [ɣ] и [ɣ']: *бухгалтер*
> [буɣа́лт'ир], разговорные междометия *ага*, ***ого*** [оɣо́], *угу*, *эге*. Кроме
> того, *старшей нормой* [= отражающей старомосковское произношение, в
> отличие от *младшей нормы*, соотв. современному литературному языку]
> допускается произношение мягкого звука [ɣ'] в словах *Господь*,
> *Господи*, в формах слова *Бог*: *Бога*, *Богу* и т. д., а также произношение мягкого звука [ɣ'] в форме *о Боге*...

That page scanned:

https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=ocY0DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA38&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=i9pv3lhhol&sig=ACfU3U2kE3PKdHmfQKHpKMZ3B8hDEiQffQ&w=1280

Comment: There is the orthoepical norm, and there are the regional variances, and people move between the regions, too. As the questioner 'has heared' some examples, the norm hardly applies here?..

Comment: The norm expressed here _agrees_ with what he has heard unexpectedly. My personal experience (as a St.Petersburg resident since birth) is different: I'm used to hearing and saying the version transcribed as [оɣо́].

Comment: Speaking of regional differences: probably that's more about _general_ pronunciation of Г in _southern_ regions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Russian_dialects

Comment: @user10578 i inquired specifically about the normative pronunciation